# Combining two input fields into one variable

Tags: javascript, html

Include two IDs into one variable, for example

```
var optionValue=document.getElementById('Input1' + " " + 'Input2');
```

That code does not work but is there any similar code that would do this?

JS

```
function addNewListItem(){
var htmlSelect=document.getElementById('list');
var value1 = document.getElementById('Input1').value;
var value2 = document.getElementById('Input2').value;
var optionValue = value1 + " " + value2;
var optionDisplaytext = value1 + " " + value2;

var selectBoxOption = document.createElement("option");
selectBoxOption.value = optionValue.value;
selectBoxOption.text = optionDisplaytext.value;
htmlSelect.add(selectBoxOption, null);
alert("Option has been added successfully");
return true;

}
```

HTML

```
<table border="0" align="left">
<tr>
<td rowspan="2">
    <select name="list" id="list" size="10" style="width:150px">
    </select>
    </td>
<tr>
<td align="right">Option Value</td>
<td align="left"><input name="Input1" type="text" id="Input1" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">Option Display Text</td>
<td align="left"><input name="Input2" type="text" id="Input2" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="left"><input name="btnAddItem" type="button" id="btnAddItem" value="Add Option" onclick="javaScript:addNewListItem();" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I've tried the above code but it will not add to a listbox? 
it just says undefined in the box

Comment: Are you trying to get an array of references to DOM elements or the single element whose id somehow combines two strings?

Comment: what is the expected content of `optionValue`?

Comment: "That code does not work but is there any similar code that would do this?" Do what? getting an element which has an ID which equals another two elements' ID concatenation? :)

Comment: It says `undefined`, because you're trying to take the `value` of a string.  There are plenty of other things that might be fixed, but first replace `optionValue.value` with just `optionValue`, and the same for `optionDisplaytext`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further to a comment I left, here's a full example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e);}
function newEl(tag){return document.createElement(tag);}
function newTxt(txt){return document.createTextNode(txt);}
function toggleClass(element, newStr)
{
    index=element.className.indexOf(newStr);
    if ( index == -1)
        element.className += ' '+newStr;
    else
    {
        if (index != 0)
            newStr = ' '+newStr;
        element.className = element.className.replace(newStr, '');
    }
}
function forEachNode(nodeList, func)
{
    var i, n = nodeList.length;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        func(nodeList[i], i, nodeList);
    }
}

window.addEventListener('load', mInit, false);

function mInit()
{
    byId('mBtn').addEventListener('click', onBtnClick, false);
}

function onBtnClick()
{
    var value1 = document.getElementById('Input1').value;
    var value2 = document.getElementById('Input2').value;
    var optionValue = value1 + " " + value2;

    var newOpt = newEl('option');
    newOpt.value = optionValue;         // this line sets the value given to a form by this option

    newOpt.appendChild( newTxt(optionValue) );  // this line adds the text viewable on the page

    byId('mSelect').appendChild(newOpt);
}

</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <label>Input 1: <input id='Input1' value='value1'/></label>
    <label>Input 2: <input id='Input2' value='value2'/></label>
    <br>
    <select id='mSelect'></select><button id='mBtn'>Add to list</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! this is what I needed to get started :)

Answer (score 2):

Elements are text inputs ? Then somethink like below will work :

```
var value1 = document.getElementById('Input1').value;
var value2 = document.getElementById('Input2').value;
var optionValue = value1 + " " + value2;
```

Comment: Hi, I've used this but it does not appear into the list box, is there any reason for this? thanks :)

Comment: @user2341069 - You haven't added any text to it! I.e <option value='something'>_some_text_here_</option> - You can append the result of document.createTextNode("_some_text_here_"); to the option before you add it to the list.

Comment: @enhzflep I'm sorry I don't really understand

Comment: Okay, I'll add a full solution. Just gimme 5 mins.

Answer (score 0):

I interpreted your question as follows:

1. Get n-number of elements by id.

You can do this with the following block:

**HTML**

```
<span id="foo">Foo</span>
<span id="bar">Bar</span>
<span id="foo1">Foo</span>
<span id="bar1">Bar</span>
```

**JS**

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('#foo, #bar');
console.log(nodes);
```

You can then derive any data you want from each matched node.